# How to find the ball?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

i have $E=\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and $$d(f,g)=\int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|dx$$
i want to find $B_d(2,1)$

$$B_d(2,1)=\{f\in E, \int_0^1 |f(x)-2|dx<1\}$$

In the case where $f(x)\leq 2$ then $\int_0^1 |f(x)-2|dx=\int_0^1 -f(x)+2dx$ so i find that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx>1$

In the case where $f(x)\geq 2$ then $\int_0^1 |f(x)-2|dx=\int_0^1 f(x)-2dx$ so i find that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx<3$

what can i say ?

how to continue please.

Comment: $B_d(2,1) = 2 + B_d(0,1)$, and the last is the open unit ball in $L^1(0,1)$.

Comment: at this moment we don't know what is L^1

Comment: However, you cannot say more. The set is too unstructured.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp ... it's the open unit ball of $L^1(0,1)$ intersected with $C(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, martini.

Comment: @Mirko that's what i do please see my edite

Comment: split $[0,1]$ into sets $A=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)<2\}$ and $B=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)>2\}$. Each of $A$ and $B$ is measurable and you could take integrals $a=\int_A |f(x)-2|dx = \int_A 2-f(x) dx$ and $b=\int_B |f(x)-2|dx=\int_B f(x)-2 dx$. Then $\int_0^1 |f(x)-2|dx=a+b$ and you need $a+b<1$. What you did is not exactly the same, note the difference between $\int_0^1$ and $\int_A$. Alternatively take $\int_0^1 \max(2-f(x),0)$ (same as $\int_A 2-f(x) dx$), and $\int_0^1 \max(f(x)-2,0)$ (same as $\int_B f(x)-2 dx$).

Comment: @Mirko in the end what is the ball ?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\frac32$ for $x\in[0,1]$ is in the ball, as is easy to verify.

$g(x)=\frac52$ for $x\in[0,1]$ too.

But also $h(x)=3x+\frac12$ for $x\in[0,1]$, is in the ball.
See a [plot of this function at WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+3x%2B1%2F2+and+2+for+x+from+0+to+1), and
the [corresponding integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20%7C3x%2B1%2F2-2%7C) showing that $h$ belongs to $B_d(2,1)$.

Also see the difference function $h(x)-2$ for the above $h$ 
[at WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%203x%2B1%2F2-2%20for%20x%20from%200%20to%201).
Note that the difference is negative for $x<\frac12$ which makes the 
absolute value of the difference to be piece-wise defined, and makes necessary to split the integral in two pieces, to evaluate it:
$\displaystyle \int_0^1|3x+\frac12-2|\,dx=$
$\displaystyle \int_0^\frac12|3x+\frac12-2|\,dx+\int_\frac12^1|3x+\frac12-2|\,dx= $
$\displaystyle \int_0^\frac12 (2-(3x+\frac12))\,dx+\int_\frac12^1 (3x+\frac12-2)\,dx = 
\frac38+\frac38=\frac34<1$.

In general, given any $f\in C([0,1],\mathbb R)$, in order to compute the integral $\int_0^1 |f(x)-2|\,dx$ you may need to split $[0,1]$ into sets $A=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)<2\}$ and $B=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)>2\}$.
Each of $A$ and $B$ is (Lebesgue) measurable and you could take integrals  $a=\int_A|f(x)−2|\,dx=\int_A(2−f(x))\,dx$ and $b=\int_B|f(x)−2|dx=\int_B(f(x)−2)\,dx$.
Then $\int_0^1 |f(x)−2|\,dx=a+b$ and you need $a+b<1$.
(For the above function $h$ we have $A=[0,\frac12)$ and $B=(\frac12,1]$.)

What you did in your question is not exactly the same, note the difference between $\int_0^1$ and $\int_A$. Alternatively (to avoid notation like 
$\int_A\,$) take $\int_0^1 \max(2−f(x),0)\,dx$ (same as $\int_A (2−f(x))\,dx)$, and $\int_0^1 \max(f(x)−2,0)\,dx$ (same as $\int_B (f(x)−2)\,dx$).

The precise answer is the definition of $B_d(2,1)$ as already stated in your question, and the three functions listed above are only illustrative. There are many more, and the structure of the sets $A$ and $B$ may be complicated.

For example, let $s(x)=2+3x\sin(\frac{\pi}x)$ for $x\in(0,1]$, and $s(0)=2$. [See plot at WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%202%2B3x*sin%28%5Cpi%2Fx%29%20and%202%20for%20x%20from%200%20to%201).
Then $s$ is in the ball, see  the [corresponding integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_%280.01%29%5E1%20%7C2%2B3x*sin%28%5Cpi%2Fx%29-2%7C) (where
I replaced $0$ with $0.01$ to help WA compute it numerically).
Compare with the graphs of 
[the positive part](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+max%282%2B3x*sin%28%5Cpi%2Fx%29%29-2,0%29++for+x+from+0+to+1,+y+from+0+to+2.06) $\max(s(x)-2,0)$, and
the (absolute value of) [the negative part](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20max%282-%282%2B3x*sin%28%5Cpi%2Fx%29%29,0%29%20%20for%20x%20from%200%20to%201,%20y%20from%200%20to%202.06) $\max(2-s(x),0)$,
of the difference function $s(x)-2$.